# Is sharing with Direct Connect DC++ secure?

Tags: exploit, file-upload, p2p

As I have some useful software that I want to share with friends and I don't like to get involved with torrents, DC++ (P2P client for sharing and chatting) seems a good way to do it, but I'm not sure if there is a risc for my system (Windows 10) to get Exploited/Hacked? I know that the download is dangerous and you have to trust the uploader, but if I only upload is there any danger?

Software Client: DC++ 0.851 or later http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/
Host OS: Windows 10 + default firewall

Comment: can you connect in active mode?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: what do you mean by active mode? The way it works is: 1) Install DC++ 2) Share folder from your computer 3) The rest in the channel where you shared can access it any time your DC++ client is active and download it (P2P) 4) You can download too (but I want to know if you only upload if there is any way that somebody can exploit vulnerability in my system Win10 with default firewall)

Comment: There are known exploits but from what I found I deduce the only thing other clients can do is DDoS atack and BSOD in the worst case, but it seems most vulns are fixed. As I'm not an expert in security prefere to ask over here if somebody knows any dangerous case so I can decide if useit or not.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Last night my connection just died for no reason. No! It won't connect in Active Mode so I can restrain the passive users but as I see it's not warranty of anything. May be the only positive thing is that the exposure range of my IP address toward the group of users.